# Prolog buildling a list of strings recursively

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm writing a program that enumerates all the possible trees that can be made out of n nodes and the output is a list of strings.  Each string is set of parentheses, representing the nodes in a tree.  Here's my code so far:

```
gZero(X) :- X > 0.
isZero(X) :- X =:= 0.
minusOne(X,Y) :- Y is X-1.
addOne(X,Y) :- Y is X+1.

find_trees(0,0,X,[Y|X]).

find_trees(N,D,Str,[Trees]) :-
    (isZero(D),string_concat(Str,'(',X),minusOne(N,I),addOne(D,K) ->
        find_trees(I,K,X,[Tree]));
    (gZero(N),gZero(D),string_concat(Str,'(',X),minusOne(N,I),addOne(D,K) ->
        find_trees(I,K,X,[Tree]));
    (gZero(D),string_concat(Str,')',X),minusOne(D,K) ->
        find_trees(N,K,X,[Tree])).
```

The program is recursive and keeps track of the number of nodes that have been placed and your current depth in the tree, and when all the nodes have been placed and you're at depth 0, there should be a parenthetical string which you add to a list.  The plan was to have the line

```
find_trees(0,0,X,[Y|X]).
```

be my base case, but as I found out Prolog just begins constructing the next string and continues doing so forever.

My next thought was to introduce a new conditional in the main find_trees body that was a little something like this:

```
find_trees(N,D,Str,[Trees]):-
    (isZero(N), isZero(D)-> 
        ????)
```

I just introduce another conditional to check if we're at the base case, however I'm not sure what to put in the body so that Prolog will be able to determine that the value of [Trees] is a list of parenthetical strings.  Are there any thoughts as to how to make a base case for this?

EDIT:  I've fixed the infinite recursion, but the program still never "sees" my base case and fails instead.  Any ideas why?

The fix was to add another condition so that the only true find_trees clause when both N and D were zero was the base case.

Comment: What kind of trees, binary trees? Can you show what result you expect for some small number, for example 3? Is there a particular reason why you are using strings and string concatenation instead of normal lists? And there seems to be something fishy with those conditionals there.... why do you need them?

Comment: The trees can have any number of children.

Example result for N = 3: [((())) , (()())]

I'm using string concatenation because that's the way I had to do it for a previous assignment and I'm trying to do the assignment in other languages to learn them.

I don't know if I need the other conditionals, I'm honestly pretty terrible at prolog.

Comment: Check out the cut operator '!'. Try placing it at the end of your base case as such: find_trees(0,0,X,[Y|X]),!                  I don't have a Prolog environment handy but that seems to be what you're looking for. (http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44)

Comment: Which operator should come after the cut?

Comment: @ChristianBaker I believe it would be the '.' to end that case.

Comment: @rosshsr I tried that and I got an error.  "Full-stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2"  I think a cut has to be used between two clauses.

Comment: The "string" type in Prolog was only meant for "text" that comes from the outside, needs very little transformations, and is eventually written out. For Prolog, a proper list is a much better data type for this purpose.

Comment: With it, you could maybe have a tree of size 1: `[]`, a tree of size 2: `[[]]`, and trees of size 3: `[[[]]]` and `[[],[]]`.